# Best Julia library for neural networks

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, julia

I have been using this library for basic neural network construction and analysis.

However, it does not have support for building multi-layered neural networks, etc.

So, I would like to know of any nice libraries for doing advanced neural networks and Deep Learning in Julia.

Comment: https://github.com/dmlc/MXNet.jl

Comment: @itdxer Thank you for the link. Can you put that as an answer by elaborating about it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Mocha.jl](https://github.com/pluskid/Mocha.jl) - Mocha is a Deep Learning framework for Julia, inspired by the C++ framework Caffe.

Project with good [documentation](http://mochajl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and examples.
Can be run on CPU and GPU backend.

Comment: I think they stopped developing Mocha and MXNet is the way to go forward. See malmaud's comment here: https://github.com/pluskid/Mocha.jl/issues/157

Comment: I've used Mocha for a while, it's got some issues and lacks a community, I concur that MXNet is where active development is. There's also a Julia wrapper for Tensorflow: https://github.com/malmaud/TensorFlow.jl  (disclamer: I haven't used either, MXNet or the TF Julia Wrapper)

Answer (score 9):

> MXNet Julia Package - flexible and efficient deep learning in Julia

https://github.com/dmlc/MXNet.jl

Pros

- Fast
- Scales up to multi GPUs and distributed setting with auto parallelism.
- Lightweight, memory efficient and portable to smart devices.
- Automatic Differentiation

Cons

- Doesn't have yet low level operations for algorithm implementation. But they are working on this issue (https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet/issues/586)

Answer (score 5):

Just to add a more recent (2019) answer: [Flux](https://github.com/FluxML/Flux.jl).

```
Flux is an elegant approach to machine learning. It's a 100% pure-Julia stack,
and provides lightweight abstractions on top of Julia's native GPU and
AD support. Flux makes the easy things easy while remaining fully hackable.
```

For example:

```
model = Chain(
  Dense(768, 128, σ),
  LSTM(128, 256),
  LSTM(256, 128),
  Dense(128, 10),
  softmax)

loss(x, y) = crossentropy(model(x), y)

Flux.train!(loss, data, ADAM(...))
```

Answer (score 3):

As of Oct 2016 there's also a [Tensorflow wrapper for Julia](https://github.com/malmaud/TensorFlow.jl).

Answer (score 1):

One newer library to look at as well is [Knet.jl](https://github.com/denizyuret/Knet.jl). It will do things like use GPUs under the hood.